# Where to Initialize Shared Preferences for better performance

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I am following Single Activity-Multiple Fragments design pattern where navigation between fragments is done via Navigation Graph.

I need Shared Preference for the app.
However, where should I initialize it ?
Inside Activity or inside Fragment ?

In case, If I need to initialize inside fragments, then shall I do the initialization in `onCreate()` callback of Fragment.

I studied all the Activity and Fragment Lifecycle before posting this question.
But I feel like initialize Shared Preference in Fragment then every time the fragment is destroyed/re-created the initialization will happen.
Hence need guidance to build a performant and robust solution.

Please advice.

Comment: as you know you will need to pass context to SP and it will be better to use it separately in fragments and activities

Comment: `Hence need guidance to build a performant and robust solution.` i doubt the initialization of shared prefs will make enough of a difference to impact this...

Comment: I'd suggest if you're following MVVM architecture pattern then shared preferences should be initialized at repository layer or else at application class and accessed via some helper class methods etc.

Comment: Probably the Application class if you have extended it, otherwise create a helper class which is a singleton, will have a single instance of the sharedPref.